# Server HTTPS access not working after re-install

Tags: ssl-certificate, https, certificate-authority

I've setup a Citadel groupware server, plus its WebCit web admin interface. It worked well with HTTPS access.
However, I had to reinstall the server, and when I try to access the server again via HTTPS, I get the following error in Firefox:

> You have received an invalid
>   certificate.  Please contact the
>   server administrator or email
>   correspondent and give them the
>   following information:
>
> Your certificate contains the same
>   serial number as another certificate
>   issued by the certificate authority. 
>   Please get a new certificate
>   containing a unique serial number.
>
> (Error code:
>   sec_error_reused_issuer_and_serial)

What can I do on the server side to alleviate this problem? Or is it simply a matter of resetting something in Firefox?? What would be a way to prevent this problem in the first place?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this error before while using FireFox with a WiFi router - it's annoying, because FF does not behave as you'd expect (i.e. let you add an exception and be done with it).

Granted, the problem *is* with your SSL certificate (it should have a new serial number when it is generated) but because the cert is generated with a hard-coded value it is going to be easier to apply a workaround for FireFox.

Here's the fix that worked for me:

> Thinking "How does it know?" I thought
>   it must be storing the certificate
>   elsewhere. I shut down Firefox, opened
>   my profile directory, found cert8.db,
>   renamed it and started Firefox. The
>   cert8.db file was recreated and I was
>   able to add the exception for the new
>   certificate.

[Same Serial Number of Certificate Error](http://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?comments_parentId=1519&forumId=1) at FireFox Support

Answer (score 1):

## Quick dirty fix

You can solve it very fast by erasing **cert9.db**, **cert_override.txt** but you lose your certs.

## Good fix

Follow https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Certificate-contains-the-same-serial-number-as-another-certificate.

NOTE: In my case I was not able to find the item at `Authorities` in **step 9** and I had to:

1. Find the certificate with `certutil -d sql:/path/to/firefox/certs -L`.
2. Remove the certificate with `certutil -d sql:/path/to/firefox/certs -D -n cert_name`.